# how do I make mvn cobertura:cobertura not run more tests than mvn test

Tags: java, maven, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I'm working on [a project](https://github.com/Fedict/fts-sign-validation) that uses the [CEF DSS library](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/display/CEFDIGITAL/DSS) to handle digital signatures. This library comes with a large test suite, which obviously we're not interested in and thus it isn't run on `mvn test`.

We wanted to create code coverage reports for our test suite, as part of a push to increase test coverage, and my first try there was to run `mvn cobertura:cobertura` to get a cobertura report. However, for some reason, this now runs the full test suite of the CEF DSS component, which is not something I'm interested in.

Why does this happen? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure that you run `mvn test` and `mvn cobertura:cobertura` in the same dir and that your local projects' `src` dirs look like on GitHub, i.e. without further sources?

Comment: @GeroldBroser yes. All I did was change the configuration of our CI system so the line that used to read `mvn test` now reads `mvn cobertura:cobertura`. CI takes care to ensure that no files that aren't committed (i.e., no further sources and no precompiled files) are not there when the job is started.

Comment: Can you supply the relevant parts ([some of] the parts where the CEF DSS tests are performed) of your build job log?

Comment: Can't do it right now, but will do so ASAP

Answer (score 0):

See [cobertura:cobertura](https://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html):

> **Description:**
>
> Instrument the compiled classes, run the unit tests and generate a Cobertura report.
>
> **Attributes:**
>
> - ...
> - Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `test` prior to executing itself.

There is no optional parameter to skip this.

But, you use this library with:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- DSS -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss</groupId>
                <artifactId>dss-...</artifactId>
                <version>${dss.version}</version>
            ...
```

The `test` phase usually runs test code in your project's `src/test/java` directory. I can't comprehend (yet) why the library's tests are performed.

BTW:

- If you configure a dependency in `<dependencyManagement>`, e.g. with `<exclusions>`, you don't have to repeat that configuration when actually using it (in your child projects' POMs). That's what `<dependencyManagement>` is for. :)
- `<dependency><scope>compile` is the default. You don't have to declare it explicitely (in `signandvalidation-ws`' POM).